# remote connection (AweSun and AnyDesk) - Control and Shift key stick when pressed for 1 or more seconds

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm having a problem that i need to access another computer through remote connection (AweSun and AnyDesk) and when i press Control or Shift key for one second or more and release, it sticks and keeps holding on remote computer

This bug is VERY ANNOYING, because i need to unfocus the remote connection window and focus again to unstick these keys

Do you guys know any solution? I really need it *and i suffered to type this due to these bugs, had to type with my phone on computer lol*

Target computer: Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

P.S.: Just found out by the worst way possible that Windows key also sticks ;-;

edit: sticky keys aren't enabled in both computers

Comment: Check to see if Sticky Keys is enabled on the remote computer.

Comment: no, it's disabled

Comment: I also experience this annoying problem very frequently. It seems to help to send ctrl+alt+del to the remote machine using the flash button in anydesk.

Comment: Looks like in addition to sending ctrl+alt+del, i have to exit the opened screen with escape button, this trick seems to always "unstuck" the shift key problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a long-running problem in AnyDesk. Some example articles:

- [CTRL and ALT keys stuck after pressing them](https://www.reddit.com/r/AnyDesk/comments/d62fpl/ctrl_and_alt_keys_stuck_after_pressing_them/)
- [Shift key is stuck](https://www.reddit.com/r/AnyDesk/comments/mc35gi/shift_key_is_stuck/).

This doesn't happen with other remote-control programs, in case you are able
to switch to some other alternative of AnyDesk.

The solutions that were claimed as working for some people:

- Pressing rapidly the stuck key
- Rapidly cycling through several of the keys
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (both left & right), <kbd>Shift</kbd> (both left & right) and
  <kbd>Win</kbd>
- Typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> followed by
  <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- If it's only one <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key that causes the problem, say the left one,
  disable it using a program such as SharpKeys and always use the other one.

Comment: More than a year later and this is still happening. It seems it happens on low speed connection, at least low speed client side.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I found to work best until now is to open the on-screen keyboard and pressing both Shift keys a few times.

Comment: What I do is just spank the keys a few times and it works normally again, lol