# I cannot press Shift key when remotely controlling another computer through AnyDesk

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-control, anydesk

I saw that people are complaining that shift key may be stuck at AnyDesk

[remote connection (AweSun and AnyDesk) - Control and Shift key stick when pressed for 1 or more seconds](https://superuser.com/questions/1652512/remote-connection-awesun-and-anydesk-control-and-shift-key-stick-when-presse)

But I can't find anyone who's experiencing "can't even press press Shift key" on AnyDesk like me.

So I can't type things like special characters "$%@* or capital letter because I can't press shift key.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem of <kbd>Shift</kbd> not being passed on to a client appears to be a [known issue](https://github.com/symless/synergy-core/issues/233). It might have been fixed, so check [AnyDesk](https://anydesk.com/en) to update to the latest version.

You might try one of the suggested alternatives:

- Use the *right* <kbd>Shift</kbd> rather the *left* <kbd>Shift</kbd>, or *vice versa*.
- Install [KeyTweak](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/keytweak/) or [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/keytweak/) to remap keys, using a different key, such as <kbd>AltGr</kbd> to act as <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
- You might also consider one of the many [alternatives to AnyDesk](https://alternativeto.net/software/anydesk/).